# How to take an action when a text message is received in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios4

Is it possible to take an action when a text message received? like launching another app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible on a non-jailbroken iphone. Sorry :)

Jailbroken ones might be different though.

Comment: What about running the app on background and check it in time intervals?

Comment: You can't run code in the background like that. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Taking action when a specified text message received.