# How to make iOS launch an application on received specific sms?

Tags: ios, ios11, ios12

I have read the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225761/how-to-take-an-action-when-a-text-message-is-received-in-ios) answered in 2011. I need to write an application when a specific SMS received and after launch my application in iOS. Is it still not possible in latest iOS versions?

Comment: Still not possible.

Comment: @Losiowaty is there any other way to achieve this task?

Comment: Kind of. If you send push notification and user interacts with it, your app will be launched. Or you can include a deeplink in the SMS - when user taps the link, your app will be launched. There is no way to do it automagically though. User interaction is mandatory.

Comment: @Losiowaty Thank you for the response.